# Seaport and ferry dock and airport

Tags: simcity-2013

Here is my simple question, how do you build a ferry terminal ?
How do you build a seaport ? (provided it is different fom ferry terminal)
How do you build an airport ?

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

you need a traffic department - you unlock this by upgrading your town hall.
You can then place the traffic department as an expansion for your town hall.

(If the buildings have slightly different names - please look at the closest match - i have not played the game in english language)

Btw. you should get a tooltip how to unlock them when hovering the locked "ferry terminal" etc. in build menu..

Comment: Ok, my quesdtion was more about where in the menus can I find a seaport to build ? (same for airport ?)

Comment: @ArnaultBonafos you should find the desired buildings either in "Mass Transit" Menu (Shift + T) or in the tourism - Submenu of "City Specialization" (Shift + B)

Comment: Ok, but how do I shape the seashore so that it becomes possible to set the seaport ?